# Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was inspecting my page and I got this warning:

> Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343

I've also seen:

> Blink deferred a task in order to make scrolling smoother. Your timer tasks should take less than 50ms to run to avoid this. Please see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail and https://crbug.com/574343#c40 for more information.

What is this?

[image]

Comment: Did you read http://crbug.com/574343 ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This occurs when Blink (Chrome's rendering engine) decides to delay executing a timer (like a function passed to `requestAnimationFrame`, `setTimeout`, or `setInterval`) because those functions are generally taking >50ms to execute **and** there is user touch input.  It's done to prioritize handling user input (like scrolls and taps) above what the site is doing.

If you've encountered this message, then its likely your users will get similar behavior. Here's **how to reproduce** this scenario:

1. Have long-running javascript that is triggered via timers
2. Be on mobile (or emulating it with DevTools device mode)
3. Have touch input, scrolling with finger down on the screen is the most reliable. Tapping or flinging the page may also trigger it, but it is less likely and harder to reproduce.
4. The devtools' experimental *CPU throttling* will make the JS take longer and give you a better chance of seeing it.

The method for **how to solve** this is directly from the [referenced issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574343#c40) in the console message down in comment 40:

1. Record a timeline on the page that is triggering the console message about deferral.
2. Select the entire timeline and open the "Event Log" pane near the bottom of the window.
3. Enter "Timer Fired" into the filter text field. (See image at bottom)
4. Look for timers in the list whose "Total Time" exceeds 50 milliseconds. These are the problematic ones. (Note that timers that exceed 10 milliseconds can also trigger this message in some cases where the browser is processing a user gesture. )

You want these functions to execute faster or less frequently.

[image: Timer fired filter on timeline]

Comment: Newer versions of Chrome have this feature in the 'Performance' tab, in case you're having trouble finding it.