# Angular Mouseup Doesn't Seem To Fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I believe I have a question that has to do with this: [Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367200/deferred-long-running-timer-tasks-to-improve-scrolling-smoothness).

I have in issue in mobile only where a mouseup event does not fire. I believe it is some kind of issue with the fact that I am using `$interval()`? I'm firing it quite often does that in some way make it impossible for the mobile browser to catch other events?

My code:

```
$scope.problem = {onHammer : function(event) {
        var count = 0;
        $scope.promisey.promise = $interval(function () { 
           count++;
         if (count > 3)
         {
        //alert("Trigged Press Down Clear");
        console.log(event);
        var itemValue = event.target.attributes.data.value;
        for (var r = 0; r < $scope.itemsSelected.length; r++) {
            if ($scope.itemsSelected[r].bread == itemValue) {
                for (var x = 0; x < $scope.breads.length; x++) {
                    if ($scope.breads[x].Name == itemValue) {
                        $scope.breads[x].selected = [""];
                        console.log($scope.breads);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $scope.itemsSelected.splice(r, 1);
                $scope.calculate();
                event.target.attributes.datalastManipulation.value = new Date();
                break;
            }
        }
        }
        }, 40);
    },
    onHammerUp: function(event){
        //alert("Up");
        console.log(event);
        $interval.cancel($scope.promisey.promise);
    },
```

`onHammer()` is called on `ng-mousedown` and `onHammerUp()` on `ng-mouseup`. What ends up happening is that `mouseup()` never cancels the `$interval()` so I get an infinite number of `console.log()` mentioning the mousedown event but never the mouseup. What am I doing wrong in mobile?

**Edit: HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="bread in breads | filter:{ Name: textInputSearch } | filter:{ Type: toggleV }">
<div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<img id="@{{bread.Name}}" ng-mousedown="$parent.problem.onHammer($event)" ng-mouseup="$parent.problem.onHammerUp($event)" ng-click="$parent.problem.select($event)" ng-class="bread.selected" ng-src="images/items/@{{bread.Picture}}" data="@{{bread.Name}}" datalastManipulation="" dataprice="@{{bread.Price}}" style="cursor:pointer;width: 90%;" class="disableSave" oncontextmenu="return false;"></img><i ng-if="bread.NotAvailable" class="cali fa fa-calendar"></i><p>@{{bread.Name}} <i style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="info(bread.Name)" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>
</div>
```

I checked my chrome timeline in the dev tools and I do have long frames that are causing the issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I don't understand why the Timer Fired keeps going even on desktop logging where the mouseup should cancel the timer being fired. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using a setTimeout at onHammerUp like this: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23053906/

Comment: @Lucio doesn't solve the problem sadly, just the same infinite log of the mousedown event with no corresponding log of the mouseup event

Comment: Can you please paste the HTML too?

Comment: @Lucio HTML posted.